# How to calculate Lyapunov Exponent in R?

Tags: r

I use the following code to calculate Lyapunov Exponent. But it cannot be used to calculate Lyapunov exponent for short time series. Any suggestion?

```
  # Lyapunov Exponent
  if(freq > N-10)
      stop("Insufficient data")
  Ly <- numeric(N-freq)
  for(i in 1:(N-freq))
  {
    idx <- order(abs(x[i] - x))
    idx <- idx[idx < (N-freq)]
    j <- idx[2]
    Ly[i] <- log(abs((x[i+freq] - x[j+freq])/(x[i]-x[j])))/freq
    if(is.na(Ly[i]) | Ly[i]==Inf | Ly[i]==-Inf)
      Ly[i] <- NA
  }
  Lyap <- mean(Ly,na.rm=TRUE)
  fLyap <- exp(Lyap)/(1+exp(Lyap))
```

Comment: Have you tried using the [tseriesChaos](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tseriesChaos/) package?

Comment: yes, but it didn't work for me

Comment: "Didn't work". Can you elaborate? Returned an error? Produced unexpected results?